# Updating from antd4 to antd5 error TS1005 in '../grid'

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have a project that is built using antd4. I went and upgraded it by running `npm install antd@latest` and installed version 5.5.0 Now when I start the project I get this error

```
TypeScript error in C:/Darwin-Web/node_modules/antd/es/col/index.d.ts(1,20):
',' expected.  TS1005

  > 1 | import { Col, type ColProps, type ColSize } from '../grid';
      |                    ^
    2 | export type { ColProps, ColSize };
    3 | export default Col;
```

I'm using node version 16.20.0 and react ^16.13.1. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which version of TypeScript are you working with?

Comment: 5.0.4 - TypeScript Version

Comment: Before upgrading to version 5, did you first upgrade to the latest version of 4 as stated in https://shorturl.at/gnFX9?

Comment: I have it running smoothly on antd 4.24.10

Comment: It seems to be on any import that imports a `type`. The files are also using Typescript 5.0.4